# My React state object is being set up only on the second try, why?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I currently struggle with a problem where I pass the item's size to `this.state.taken_size` and after that I create order item with an order or update the already existing order(just for understanding).

So when I take the size, in my `console.log()` I see that it takes needed value and it sets it up but when I pass that size in the field, it says something like `this.state.taken_size is undefined`. But when I click the second time, my taken size is passed in the field, and it works.

My code below

```
    takeSize(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        const taken_size = event.target.value
        console.log(this.state.taken_size)
        this.setState({
            taken_size:taken_size
        })
    }



    handleAddingToCart(event){
        event.preventDefault(event)
        console.log(this.state.taken_size)
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-o-i/create/', {
            item: this.state.item.id,
            user: localStorage.user_pk,
            size: this.state.taken_size, 
        }).then(res => {
          // Do other things
        })
    }
```

And my html code:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleAddingToCart}>
  <div className="product-options">
    <label>
      Size 
        <ul class="product__size-list">
          {this.state.all_sizes.map((size) => {
            return <div>
              <div onClick={this.takeSize} className="product">  
                <li value={size.pk} class="centered" >
                  <span value={size.pk}>{size.size}</span>
                </li>       
              </div>
          </div>
        })}
      </ul>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div className="add-to-cart">
    <button htmlType="submit" className="add-to-cart-btn">
      <i className="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> add to wishlist
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

If needed something else, feel free to ask.

Comment: I saw a lot of questions with this title today, state is async, place a settimeout with no time and try again

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your initial state in the constructor of the Component class so that it is not undefined like this

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    contructor() {
        super();
        // set the initial state
        this.state = {
            taken_size: 0 //or null or whatever you want
        };
    }

    /*

      Other code

     */
}
```

Also you're logging before setting the state which will log the previous state. `setState` is async. So if you want to do something after updating the state, you can use a callback as the second argument for `setState`.

```
 takeSize(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    const taken_size = event.target.value

    this.setState({
        taken_size:taken_size
    },()=>{
        console.log(this.state.taken_size)
    })
}
```

Hope this helps !